# Error on AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I am doing project Using Spring MVC java, when I make an ajax call it gives this error... which I caught using firebug -

```
>>>> Error
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -"
```

this is the POST request

```
HeadersPostResponseHTML
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
teamID  2
Source
teamID=2
```

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

AJAX Call

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function doAjaxPostTeamDelete (){
    //get the values                
    var teamID = $('#teamID').val();         
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/controller/DeleteTeam",
         data: "teamID=" + teamID,          
         success: function(response){  
             // we have the response                 
         alert("we a  in team delete");                                           
         }, 
         error: function(e){  
         alert('Error: ' + e);  
         }       
    });  
 }   
</script>
```

Comment: please update your question with information on how you're generating your ajax call.

Comment: What does the server side say? Does it expect a DELETE type in the request?

Comment: Does the endpoint `/controller/DeleteTeam` exist? Is it capable of consuming a POST?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/DeleteTeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String editDeleteRecodes(@ModelAttribute NewTeams newTeams, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){  
  Teams teams = new Teams();
  teams.setTeamID(newTeams.getTeamID());
  try{
   teamService.delete(teams);
  }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
   map.put("error", "Check the relesse");
   System.out.println("aaaaa");
  }
      
  return "redirect:/";
  
  
 }

Comment: tht is my controller for that

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP Error 400 Bad request**

The data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was 'malformed' i.e. did not respect the **HTTP protocol** completely. So the Web server was unable to understand the request and process it.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/759319

In the internet options, go to the connections tab and makesure the there is nothing checked in the LAN Settings window, and if nothing is checked, do an IE Reset (After doing RESET, you would loose the passwords which are saved on the personal website)

Comment: Added some solutions, please try that